# Using JavaScript how can I get the string inside of this HTML element by ID?

Tags: javascript, html

Using JavaScript, how can I get the string inside of this HTML element, with the id being recItemString_GPLA\|input? Inside the element there is a string with "qty" (without quotes) that I'm trying to capture. When I inspect the element I get:

```
<input data-oj-internal="" type="text" readonly="" placeholder="" class="oj-inputtext-input oj- 
component-initnode" id="recItemString_GPLA|input"> == $0.
```

Above that element in DevTools there is:

```
<oj-input-text :id="[[fieldId()]]" validators="[[validators]]" on-value- 
changed="[[valueChanged.bind($data)]]" on-valid-changed="[[validChanged]]" 
value="{{value}}" required="[[required]]" readonly="[[readOnly]]" messages- 
custom="[[messagesComputed]]" display-options="[[displayOptions]]" help=" 
[[help]]" id="recItemString_GPLA" class="oj-inputtext oj-form-control oj- 
component oj-read-only oj-complete"><input data-oj-internal="" type="text" 
readonly="" placeholder="" class="oj-inputtext-input oj-component-initnode" 
id="recItemString_GPLA|input"></oj-input-text>
```

I have not been able to gather the string inside the element to display it to the console.

Using the pluggin SelectorGadget the element XPath is: //*[(@id = "recItemString_GPLA\|input")]

When I try and query oj-input-text directly to the console the console returns [Object NodeList]

Here is a screenshot of the inspected element:
[image: screen2]

Comment: `<input>` elements don't have *string inside of them* (text content), you're probably looking to get a text node that is after this `<input>`, try: `document.querySelector('#recItemString_GPLA\\|input').nextSibling.textContent`

Comment: document.getElementById('recItemString_GPLA|input').value

Comment: Titus, I tried console.log("The next try is: " + document.querySelector('#recItemString_GPLA\\|input').nextSibling.textContent); and the console response I get is: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of null
    at pullCellValue (<anonymous>:45:102)

Comment: @AdamH I tried console.log("The value of the input is: " + document.getElementById('recItemString_GPLA|input').value); and the console response I get is: The value of the input is:

Comment: I guess there is no `Node` after the `<input/>`, you should edit your question to add more context (more of the HTML) and specify exactly what you're trying to retrieve.

Comment: Ok Titus, I will try add more context to the question

Comment: I've added some more context. @Titus would something like this be headed in the wrong direction? : querySelector('input[name="recItemString_GPLA"]').value.split('|')[1];

Comment: I looked closely at your markup. It is not valid HTML(there is no element `<oj-input-text>` in HTML). But, assuming you *really* want to get something from the embedded `<input>`, that raises the question: which "text"? Do you want to get the current *value* (the input element is currently defined empty)?

Comment: cars10m, the code above that I provided was what I see in the console when I inspect the HTML element. The problem really is, that I'm having trouble finding how I can identify the "thing" that I need to capture the "text" inside of it. It does seem to have to do with a NodeList I believe, but I'm not certain. I did explain part of the string/text "qty" is what I'm trying to at least print to the console.It's literally on the screen, I just can't capture it and display it to the console at all.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no"qty" to be seen in the code sample you provided, so I am a bit lost as to where to look for it. :-/

Comment: cars10m, yes that is the problem I'm facing. The string is on the screen, but I can't find it anywhere. Mainly due to the fact that the application has been written with very little consideration to maintainability. The value attribute in the code snippet below (value="some text inside ...") is something you added and not present in when I inspect the element. If that were the case I would know what to do. I could take a screenshot and add it to the question, but I think that most programmers are stumped with this one.

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery you can escape special characters like this:

```
$('#recItemsString\\_GPLA\\|input');
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this would help me?

Answer (score 1):

I am really not sure which text is supposed to be produced. In the following snippet I added an input value to be displayed.

```js
const qs=s=>document.querySelector(s);

console.log(qs('#recItemString\\_GPLA\\|input').value)
```

```html
<oj-input-text :id="[[fieldId()]]" 
  validators="[[validators]]" 
  on-value-changed="[[valueChanged.bind($data)]]"
  on-valid-changed="[[validChanged]]" 
  value="{{value}}" 
  required="[[required]]"
  readonly="[[readOnly]]"
  messages-custom="[[messagesComputed]]"
  display-options="[[displayOptions]]"
  help="[[help]]" 
  id="recItemString_GPLA" 
  class="oj-inputtext oj-form-control oj-component oj-read-only oj-complete">

 <input data-oj-internal="" 
  type="text" value="some text inside ..."
  readonly=""
  placeholder=""
  class="oj-inputtext-input oj-component-initnode" 
  id="recItemString_GPLA|input">
  
</oj-input-text>
```

Comment: I've added a screenshot to show the string of the element that I inspected.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that -> value="some text inside ..." does not show when I inspect the element.